# footnotes background color

Tags: footnotes, backgrounds

In the usual Latex document classes, is there a simple way to have a background colour behind the footnotes only? It would probably help the reader in the organization of a page between main text and footnotes.

Comment: If you place footnotes at the bottom of the page, with footnote marks and smaller type, I doubt that colour background will help the reader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have not tried this yet, but I can imagine that the `colorbox` environment from the standard `color` package might work for this. Use this in your preamble:

```
\usepackage{color}
```

And create your footnote like this:

```
\footnote{\colorbox{declared-color}{text}}
```

Comment: The problem with that is that the footnote will no longer get broken across pages.  This really has to be done in the output routine when `\box\footins` is getting used.